# Jupyter Lab 2.0 - Notebook to .py file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

What is the best (quickest) way to take a .ipynb and make a .py file? Is there a feature or option within Jupyter Lab 2.0 to have it automatically create the .py file when you start a new notebook?

Comment: FILE > EXPORT NOTEBOOK AS.. >EXPORT NOTEBOOK TO EXECUTABLE SCRIPT

Answer (score 1):

In bowser's jupyter lab tab, go to File ->Export Notebook As ->Export Notebook to Executable Script

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[JupyText](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension keeps the .ipynb and .py in sync, so whenever you change one of them, the other file reflects also the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want programmatic solution, you can run the following in your terminal:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script "My Notebook.ipynb"
```

You can also do it in a Jupyter cell, which makes this easy to automate as a step in your notebook (Works in jupyterlab==3.1.10):

```
try:
    get_ipython() # Ensures export only runs when running interactively
    !jupyter nbconvert --to script "My Notebook.ipynb"
except: pass
```